# Cache to save data

Tags: html, storage

Is there a storage like LocalStorage in the browser, where I can save data(in my case a todo list), but not for every user his own storage, but for every user the same. Is there a storage in the browser for that? I don't want to use a database

Answer (score 0):

No … because not every user is using the same browser so no data stored in the browser can be shared between every user.

(NB: Local Storage is a database).

Comment: I thought that's there something on webserver sites

Comment: Sometimes people bundle database servers and webservers together for convenience.

Comment: something like XXAMP?

Comment: Yes, that is such an example.

Comment: hmm, that's not that what I want. I want to use my webserver to store the data

Comment: That's not what web servers do.

Comment: Sure it is *possible*, you can write an HTTP server which does that, and I have, but its a terrible idea (I've since rewritten it to use a real database) and you won't find any off the shelf ones which does it.

Comment: ok, but is there maybe a file which I can store in my webserver and open it from the website

Comment: You could store a file on a file system that your web server can read and write from. That isn't in the web server though. Congratulations, you've just written your own database, just one that isn't very good (and will likely have problems with data integrity and file locking).

Comment: ok, then I have to install a database. Is there one for my windows pc, with is only for my network?

Comment: There are many databases that run on Windows, and you've no need for the database to have any network capabilities if the web server and database are going to run on the same computer.

Comment: I've got my webserver on my rasperry pi. but this is not mine, so I cannot install a database there.